# Combine absolute and relative (scaled) coordinates

Tags: plotting, graphics, scaling

I am using `Inset` to add an `Epilog` to a plot. The position of the images (in my case: framed numbers) can be specified as an option of `Inset`.

I would like the y-coordinate to be the same for all `Inset` elements (they are created via `Table`), relative to the plot size. Say, for example, it should be the y-coordinate of `Scaled[*,0.9]`. The x-coordinate should, for each element, be an absolute value, depending on its position in the table.

While I know how to specify relative and absolute coordinates, also as functions of the table position, I can't get `Scaled` to work for only one coordinate: specifying my `Inset` coordinates via something like

```
{*abs. value*, Scaled[.9]}
```

yields the following error message:

```
Coordinate {*abs. value*, Scaled[0.9]} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.
```

Any help on this?

---

**Update:** I also tried snippets like `Scaled[*some value*,.9][[2]]` to extract the y-coordinate, but to no avail.

Comment: You might want to use `Rescale[]` to transform absolute coordinates to relative coordinates that you can then use with `Scaled[]`.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, that might be a workaround, but I want to insert the Inset into an Epilog, the Epilog into a Plot, the Plot possibly into a Show, etc - so that I don't yet know the minimum and maximum values of y (required for `Rescale`). I could of course use a function for this [checking for min. and max. values when the plot is created], but it seems it wound end up in a rather cumbersome construct just to specify a value for y...

Answer (score 11):

Great question, to which I would like to know the answer myself, other than manual scaling as mentioned by J. M.

---

A partial solution is to use the second parameter of `Scaled`.  Here I place a point at y scaled 1/2, and x plot coordinate 9.  Note that y origin `5` must be known:

```
Graphics[{
  AbsolutePointSize[25],
  Point @ Scaled[{0, 1/2}, {9, 5}]
  },
 PlotRange -> {{5, 10}, {5, 10}},
 Frame -> True,
 GridLines -> Automatic
]
```

[image]

---

Another limited method I am aware of uses `Offset`, but that specifies position in printer's points rather than plot coordinates (resize the graphic to see the result of that):

```
Graphics[{
  AbsolutePointSize[25],
  Point @ Offset[{75, 0}, Scaled[{0, 1/2}]]
  },
 PlotRange -> {{5, 10}, {5, 10}},
 Frame -> True
]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. As with J.M.'s approach, it seems to require (at least in the first method) the knowledge of at least some minimum/maximum values, which I hope to avoid.

Comment: @Bernd Indeed, which is why I said I'd like to know the answer too.  In the past I've always used some other workaround, but it's disappointing that the mixed form {abolute, Scaled[pos]} doesn't work directly. :-/

Answer (score 4):

Following method does not require any knowledge about `PlotRange` because *MMA* knows it. :)

This function is not pretty, I suspect it will crush sometimes due to it's naive form. Report me then :)

However, it works and You can `DumpSave` it if You don't want to look at it. :)

```
 MixedCoordinates[plot_] := Composition[
  ReplaceAll[#[[1]], {
   {x_?NumericQ, Scaled@y_?NumericQ} :> {x, (#1 + Abs[#1 - #2] y) & @@ #[[2, 1, 2]]},
   {Scaled@x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {(#1 + Abs[#1 - #2] x) & @@ #[[2, 1, 1]], y}
  }] &,
 {#[[1]], Cases[#[[2]], x : Rule[PlotRange, _] :> x[[2]]]} &,
 {#, AbsoluteOptions@#} &
 ][plot]
```

Lets test it. This two `Shows` have the same content, except of second argument, `Plot` with different domain.

```
MixedCoordinates@Show[
    ListPlot[{{-.5, .5}, {.5, 2}}, PlotStyle -> Directive@AbsolutePointSize@12],
    Plot[x, {x, ##}],
    Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize@12, Blue, Point[{{.5, .5}}],
              Red, Point[{{Scaled@1, .2}}]}]
    ,
    PlotLabel -> Style["Red points have mixed coordinates", Bold, 15],
    PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
    Frame -> True, Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize@12, Red, Point[{{.4, Scaled@.1}}]},
    ImageSize -> 400, GridLines -> Automatic, BaseStyle -> Thick
] & @@@ {{-1, 1}, {-2, 2}}
```

[image]

**Possible issues:**

- `PlotRange->All` seems to be necessary at the end od `Show`
- If You want to put `Epilog` somewhere, it has to be either in `Show` or in it's first argument. Why? Because `Show` takes options from it's first argument and other's arguments options are not exposed.

**Short description:**

`MixedCoordinates@[]` is taking information from `PlotRange` given by `AbsoluteOptions`. And then, with this information it is rescaling elements `Scaled[_]`

---

**I do not consider it is finished, but it could be a good start. Looking forward for Your remarks.**

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something - why not use `PlotRange` to get the coordinate ranges in each direction?

Comment: @SimonWoods No You are not. :) I have started with this idea, then I have switched to that with `FullForm`, before I realized that `PlotRange->All` is necessary. After that I forgot about the beginning which works also good, I'll replace that, it is a little bit shorter.

Comment: Kuba, thanks for this. Since I'm not quite able to understand completely how `MixedCoordinates@[]` works just from reading the code: Does the `ReplaceAll` part manipulate any occurrence of `Scaled` in the Graphics it is applied to? So I should not use any other instances of `Scaled`?

Comment: @Bernd It should affect only `Scaled[_?NumericQ]` form, so You can use `Scaled[{_,_},{_,_}]` form somewhere else without erros but I have not tested this.

Comment: While it's not yet a perfect solution (according to Kuba's own remarks), it seems to come closest to what I am looking for (though I hoped there was a simpler way...) - so I'd award him/her the bounty?

Comment: @Bernd You should ask on chat. I am not familiar with politics about bounty. :)

Answer (score 2):

Late answer.. I thought some might find this useful:

I had a need to also use the plot aspect ratio,
   so develeped this variation on @kuba's answer..

```
 ctransform = Module[{plotrange, plotratio, aspect},
         plotrange = Last@Cases[ AbsoluteOptions[#] , 
                          x : Rule[PlotRange, _] :> x[[2]]];
         aspect =  Last@Cases[ AbsoluteOptions[#] , 
                         x : Rule[AspectRatio, _] :> x[[2]]];
         plotratio = Divide @@ (Subtract @@ # & /@ plotrange);
         ReplaceAll[#, {
       scaleratio -> 1/plotratio/aspect,
       scalev[i_, x_] :> plotrange[[i, 1]] (1 - x) + plotrange[[i, 2]] (x)}]] &;

ctransform@
  Show[{
      Plot[ x^2 + 5, {x, 1, 5}, PlotStyle -> Thick,   PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 30}}], 
      Graphics[ Table[Circle[{i,   scalev[2, .1] + .1 i scaleratio}, 
            .1 i {1, scaleratio}], {i, 1,  5}]]},   AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 30}}]
```

Note I'm not using the bultin Scaled at all, so there is no conflict issue if yuo needed to use that for something as well.

You could also do this with Composition, but it gets a bit unwieldy

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you asked for, but it will work in many situations, although not in v6 :/

```
insets = Table[Framed[i], {i, 0, 9}];

plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 10},
  Epilog -> MapIndexed[
             Translate[Inset[#1, {0, Top}, Scaled[{0.5, 1.5}]], {First@#2 - 1, 0}] &, 
             insets]
  ]
```

[image: First plot]

Combining with other plots, the insets move up automatically:

```
Show[plot, Plot[2 Cos[x], {x, -2, 8}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Second plot]

Now the above works well if the insets all have the same vertical size.  If not, one can use `Pane`:

```
SeedRandom[1];
insets2 = Table[Framed[Style[i, RandomInteger[20, 40]]], {i, 0, 9}];
vsize = Max[Rasterize[#, "RasterSize"] & /@ insets2];

Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 10},
 Epilog -> 
  MapIndexed[
   Translate[Inset[#1, {0, Top}, Scaled[{0.5, 1.5}]], {First@#2 - 1, 0}] &, 
   Pane[#, {Automatic, vsize}, Alignment -> Center] & /@ insets2]]
```

[image: Third plot]

The main way it fails to do exactly what the OP asks is that the vertical offset is relative to the (max) size of the insets, not relative to the size of the graphics.

Comment: Michael, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but your above code doesn't yield the image you attached for me. If I run your first code snippet, I get [this graph](http://i.imgur.com/VvEJd7z.png), and the second one similarly looks different.

Comment: And if I try to run the third code, I get the following error: `The specified setting for the option PaneBoxOptions, ImageSize cannot be used.`

Comment: @Bernd That's curious.  When I cut and paste the code above, it all works just as shown, on both V8.0.4 and V9.0.1 (on a Mac).  Which version of *Mathematica* are you using?  Did you try the code with a fresh kernel?  (I can get your image if I replace `{0, Top}` with `Scaled[{0, 1}]`, but I don't know why your system would behave differently than mine.)

Comment: That could indeed be the issue - I'm still on version 6. Still all the commands are already introduced in this version, so it's odd to get such a different result. A pity because I really like this proposal for its brevity.

Comment: @Bernd The reference pages say `Inset` and `Scaled` were modified in V7.  Try `Inset[#1, {Axis, Top}, Scaled[{0.5, 1.5}]]` -- maybe it will work.  There will be a problem if the axis is not at x = 0, though.  But if you know where the axis is, then it might be usable.

Comment: Unfortunately, that still gives the same plot. What a shame. :(