# How to draw an infinitely long line that automatically scales with the plot?

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to plot a function inside a `Manipulate` and draw a vertical line at some $x$ position. The scale of the plot can vary a lot depending on the `Manipulate` settings. Example:

```
h = 1;
Manipulate[
 Plot[10^f*x^3, {x, -1, 1}, 
  Epilog -> {Line[{{0.5, -h}, {0.5, h}}]}], {{f, 0}, -5, 5}]
```

Now the problem is to choose a good value for `h`: If it's too small, it's not as high as the plot. If it's too large, the line isn't drawn at all. (Sidenote: Don't try to make the line dashed or dotted. Apparently the dashing/dotting is done *before* the clipping, so *Mathematica* just freezes up if `f` gets too small.)

Ideally, I'd just want to draw a line from $y=-\infty \ldots +\infty$. Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Can't you replace `h` with `10^f` which is the maximum of the function you're plotting in the given interval ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The most natural way to do this is to use `GridLines`:

```
Manipulate[Plot[10^f*x^3, {x, -1, 1}, GridLines -> {{.5}, {}}], {{f, 0}, -5, 5}]
```

It automatically scales with the plot range, no need to add a magical scaling factor. By using `GridLinesStyle`, one can customize the appearance of the line, e.g.:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[10^f*x^3, {x, -1, 1}, GridLines -> {{.5}, {}}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]], {{f, 0}, -5, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

To see a use case, I refer to [this application](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8045/89) where I needed such functionality in an experiment where the plot range was manipulated by a user, where I could not estimate beforehand the vertical limits of the visual field (as the user might wander quite far from the baseline). `GridLines` was proven stable and it works with extreme distances.

Comment: Perfect! I was looking for a Plot option for clipping, but this is even better.

Answer (score 7):

The best options is to use mixed (scaled/absolute) coordinates, which unfortunatelly are not supported by *Mathematica*: [combine absolute and scaled...](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25647/5478)

You can always add a big number for $y$ value specification or find `Min` and `Max`, of the functions in given interval, for this purpose.

Or, use less general but faster method.

```
h = 1;
Manipulate[
  Plot[10^f*x^3, {x, -1, 1}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
       Epilog -> {Line[{Scaled[{0.75, 0}], Scaled[{0.75, 1}]}]}], 
  {{f, 0}, -5, 5}]
```

It's not so much localized, it can be also used for less convenient interval with help of `Rescale`:

```
h = 1;
Manipulate[
   Plot[10^f*x^3, {x, -E/2, 1}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
        Epilog -> {Line[{Scaled[{Rescale[.5, {-E/2, 1}], 0}], 
                         Scaled[{Rescale[.5, {-E/2, 1}], 1}]}]}]
   , {{f, 0}, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: `GridLines` is easier to use, but this is more powerful. I wish I could accept both. Thanks!

Comment: @nikie No problem, I also find `GridLines` better here :)

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: this is a safer version of the original hack:

```
Manipulate[g = Plot[10^f*x^3, {x, -1, 1}];
 Show[{g, 
   Graphics[
    Line[{0.5, #} & /@ (PlotRange /. Options[g])[[2]]]]}], {{f,0}, -5, 5}]
```

Interestingly, `PlotRange` also works as a function in 9.01:

```
PlotRange[g] == PlotRange /. Options[g]
```

> True

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Kuba yes it does, but it is a gamble (I was just being lazy). Perhaps I should re-write or delete to avoid grievance.

Comment: @Kuba removed offending code, hopefully this is more stable :-)

Comment: It is working now :) +1

Comment: @Kuba sorry for the crash - next kernel is on me :-)

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to use the `Scaled` command with two arguments: `Scaled[{dx,dy},{x0,y0}]`.
The second argument `{x0,y0}` specifies the starting point in absolute values, while the first one `{dx,dy}` specifies an offset in relative coordinates.

So one way to draw an infinitely long line at $x=0.5$ is:

```
Manipulate[
   Plot[10^f*x^3, {x, -1, 1},
         Epilog -> {Line[{Scaled[{0, -1},{0.5,0}],Scaled[{0,1},{0.5, 0}]}]}], {{f, 0},-5, 5}]
```

Answer (score 4):

This can now be done with an [`InfiniteLine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InfiniteLine.html) in `Epilog` or `Prolog` since version 10:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[10^f*x^3, {x, -E/2, 1}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
  Epilog -> InfiniteLine[{0.5, 0}, {0, 1}]], {{f, 0}, -5, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or in a separate `Show` on `Graphics`:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[10^f*x^3, {x, -E/2, 1}, PlotRangePadding -> 0]~Show~
  Graphics@InfiniteLine[{0.5, 0}, {0, 1}], {{f, 0}, -5, 5}]
```